# Fortran: error #6562: A data initialization-expr is not valid for this object

Tags: initialization, fortran

I am trying to initialize a local logical array in a Fortran subroutine to false, but I get the error:

> error #6562: A data initialization-expr is not valid for this object.

Here is my declaration:

```
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nLOW 
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nUP
  logical , dimension(nLOW:nUP)                :: leastSQUARE =  .false.
```

I get the same error if I use:

```
  integer                                      :: I
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nLOW 
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nUP
  logical , dimension(nLOW:nUP)                :: leastSQUARE =  (/ (.false., I = nLOW:nUP) /)
```

If I write:

```
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nLOW 
  integer                      , intent(in)    :: nUP
  logical , dimension(1:100)               :: leastSQUARE =   .false.
```

the subroutine compiles with zero errors. Any idea why this happens? I clearly need `leastSQUARE` with dimensions `nLOW:nUP`, so the latter is not a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the error-generating construction is forbidden by the language standard, specifically (in the Fortran 2008 version) by C506 on R503.  That constraint states

> An initialization shall not appear if object-name is a dummy argument,
>   a function result, an object in a named common block unless the type
>   declaration is in a block data program unit, an object in blank
>   common, an allocatable variable, or an automatic object.

`leastSQUARE` is just such an automatic object, one whose bounds are only known at run-time.  You'll have to initialise it separately from its declaration.

To be clear (thanks to @IanH), you will have  to execute an assignment statement to give your automatic object an initial value.  My  use of the verb *initialise* in the previous paragraph was not Fortran standard standard.

Comment: From a Fortran terminology point of view, it doesn't matter where (source code wise) the initialization happens - it cannot be initialized at all.  If the OP wants the array to have a particular value early in the execution sequence of the procedure, then they need to give the array that value using an assignment statement or similar.  Initialization implies SAVE, SAVE is inconsistent with automatic objects (something cannot retain its value (...SAVE...) when characteristics fundamental to its value can vary from call to call).